# Is the supremum of a set finite by definition?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, supremum-and-infimum

I have a question related to the definition of supremum of a set. Consider a set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. My understanding is that the supremum of $A$ is **by definition** a finite number. Hence, we have that **if and only if $A$ is bounded above then the supremum exists**. Is this correct?

> If this is correct, consider the definition of Lebesgue Integral for
>   non-negative functions here
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#Integration
>
> $\int_E fd\mu:=\sup\{\int_E sd\mu \text{ s.t. $0\leq s\leq f$, $s$
> simple}\}$
>
> and then we read "For some functions, this integral  $\int_E fd\mu$ 
>   is infinite".

My second question is: the set $\sup\{\int_E sd\mu \text{ s.t. $0\leq s\leq f$, $s$
simple}\}$ does not necessarily have an upper bound since $\int_E sd\mu$ could be equal to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. Hence, how can the supremum exist? I'm really confused on this point; any hint would be really appreciated.

Comment: It depends on the context. In some situations the sup is finite by definition, so that a set that's not bounded above has no sup. In other situations, for example typically in measure theory, we're talking about subsets of $[-\infty,\infty]$, and the sup is allowed to be $+\infty$.

Comment: By convention, if $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is unbounded above we write $\sup S = \infty$.

Comment: You are confusing supremum and maximum: the supremum can also be $+\infty$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich " In other situations, for example typically in measure theory, we're talking about subsets of [−∞,∞][−∞,∞], and the sup is allowed to be +∞+∞.": hence the supremum and infimum always exist?

Comment: @Aretino: By definition the $\sup$ is the least upper bound, so you need the set in question to be a subset of some partially ordered set and for the least upper bound to be an element of this partially ordered set.

Comment: In a *first* analysis course, usually the supremum is by definition a real number, so "finite." Later, the convention may change.

Comment: Hence the supremum and infimum always exist?

Comment: Usually it is convenient to define sup so that every subset $I$ of the real numbers admits a supremum: if $I$ is unbounded then $\sup I=+\infty$.

Comment: Note that $\int_E 0d \mu= 0$, so the set in question is non empty. Hence the $\sup$ in the last paragraph is either finite or the set in question is unbounded above.

Comment: Always exist?  In what set?  In $[-\infty,+\infty]$ yes.  But note that $\sup \varnothing = -\infty$.

Comment: Yes, if the supremum is allowed to take all real values *and* $\pm \infty$, then the supremum exists for any set of real numbers (likewise for the infimum).